# fatal error C1083 : Cannot open include file: 'mexutils.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I would like to compile a c++ file as a mex file in MATLAB namely: "mexLasso.cpp".

These are the steps I take and I get the following error. What is the problem?

**1. Put the files "mexLasso.cpp" and "mexutils.h" in a folder.**

**2. Set the compiler:**

```
 mex -setup C++
```

I recieve:

```
MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional' for C++ language compilation.
```

**3. Run the command:**

```
mex C:\...\mexLasso.cpp
```

I recieve the following error:

```
Error using mex
mexLasso.cpp
C:\...\mexLasso.cpp(33) : fatal error C1083: Cannot
open include file: 'mexutils.h': No such file or directory
```

Can somebody help us what we are missing?

Comment: This is path does not make sense: `C:\...\mexLasso.cpp` I assume you don't have a folder in C:\ named `...` containing your source code.

Comment: The path I have shorenned for the sake of simplicity. Please ignore it

Comment: I assume the problem is the path containing `mexutils.h` is not in your additional include directories for VS2013 so the compiler can not find the header.

Comment: ok, I understand, can you give me a tip how to fix it?

Comment: I should mention that the file mexLasso.cpp starts with these two headers. Can this help?

#include <mexutils.h>
#include <decomp.h>

Answer (score 1):

From the [`mex` command line tool reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#f24401), there is an argument for adding include paths:

> `-Ipathname`   Adds pathname to the list of folders to search for #include files.
>   Do not add a space between I and pathname.

Like this:

```
mex -v -IC:\path\to\mexutils_h\ mexLasso.cpp
```

Note that with `-I` you are not specifying the header, you are specifying a path containing one or more header files.

Comment: Thanks. In the example of the link you provided (-Ipathname) do I need these ?

fortfile,lapacklib 

Can you suggest me a command? Thanks

Comment: I applied:


mex -v -IC:\Users\Yashar\Desktop\CVPR2011\mexutils.h\ mexLasso.cpp

and recieved this error: 
Error using mex
mexLasso.cpp
C:\Users\Yashar\Desktop\CVPR2011\mexLasso.cpp(33) : fatal error C1083: Cannot
open include file: 'mexutils.h': No such file or directory

Error in R (line 6)
mex -v -IC:\Users\Yashar\Desktop\CVPR2011\mexutils.h\ mexLasso.cpp

Comment: @YAS From your above comment I expect it to be `mex -v -IC:\Users\Yashar\Desktop\CVPR2011\ mexLasso.cpp`

Comment: No, you are not specifying the header

Comment: You don't put the header in the path (e.g. wrong: `-IC:\Users\Yashar\Desktop\CVPR2011\mexutils.h\ `), you use the **path to the header** (i.e. `-IC:\Users\Yashar\Desktop\CVPR2011\ `). Like, @drescherjm said.  That's why I showed the example the way I did.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. I think the besy way to solve my problem is to install SPAMS in my machine and successfully compile it. I have posted the steps I take in this post :

[How to install SPAMS toolbox in Matlab 2014b under windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627540/how-to-install-spams-toolbox-in-matlab-2014b-under-windows-8-1)

Can I have your opinion there. Sorry for duplicated message, only for relevancy and importance of the discussed topic.

Many thanks.